# IQKeyboardManager issue when using navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using `IQKeyboardManager` for my iOS app.

When I first launch the app, I tap on a button which unhides a view that contains a text field. On tapping the text field, the `IQKeyboardManager` shifts the whole view upwards so that the text field is not hidden by the keyboard. But when I navigate to some other view and come back to the previous view and I click the button to unhide a view containing the text field, the `IQKeyboardManager` does not shift the view upwards.

I cannot understand the cause. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You trying it on simulator..?

Comment: The problem is on both simulator and iphone

Comment: can you share the full code of this entire view controller.

Comment: Thank you so much Ankit for the help. Actually I figured out the issue. I was disabling the IQKeyboard manager in another viewcontroller. So I reenabled it in viewwillappear which fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is better.It won't effect other VC:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [IQKeyboardManager sharedManager].enable = NO;
    [IQKeyboardManager sharedManager].enableAutoToolbar = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [IQKeyboardManager sharedManager].enable = YES;
    [IQKeyboardManager sharedManager].enableAutoToolbar = YES;
}
```

**In Swift**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
   IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
}
    
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true
   IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With Swift 5

```
import IQKeyboardManager

// add This in viewDidLoad
IQKeyboardManager.shared().disabledDistanceHandlingClasses.add(LoginViewController.self)
```